# Existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error while web scraping

Tags: python, networking, web-scraping, urllib

I am using python beautifulsoup and urllib.request to scrape weather data from the following website-

```
http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/CYTZ/
```

Following is the code to fetch the webpage

```
 # the new url created after each day
        theurl = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/CYTZ/" + theDate + "/DailyHistory.html"
        # extract the source data for analysis
        thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
```

I am able to scrape the data I need, but the program keeps terminating unexpectedly after giving few results with the following error -

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host>
```

the number of results vary each time I run the program. Is there a particular way to stop this from happening and extract all the results in a single run? Thanks

Comment: Try adding `thepage.close()` at the end. How are you calling this? In a loop?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am looping the URL for a new date each time hence calling a new webpage. should I add this command at  the end of each loop?

Comment: Add it after the `soup = ...` line.

Comment: No, that didn't work :(